# Is it technically possible to change the total amount of Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-reward, reward-schedule

Also, is it possible to change the reward cycle duration or the number of mining- reward coins?

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/38994/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/161/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/8439/5406

Answer (score 5):

Technically, yes, yes, and yes.  However, I'm not sure if we'd still call it "Bitcoin" at that point.

Any of these changes would require a hard fork, which means that the underlying rules of the system are changing in a non-backwards-compatible way.  It means that blocks/transactions from after the fork are not guaranteed to be considered valid to nodes running software for pre-fork.

So, to change Bitcoin like this in practice would require convincing the entire rest of the world to agree with the changes.  Anything less, and you will end up with two versions: the original and the one with your changes.  Which one gets the title "Bitcoin"?  I don't know.  That's a non-technical question, and a point of contention.

For an example of this in practice, see [Bitcoin Cash](https://www.investopedia.com/tech/bitcoin-vs-bitcoin-cash-whats-difference/).

Comment: that means : change is possible technically, but it required to be soft-fork nor it will cause a new hard-fork . thank you for your clear answer. my question was because i have thought about what bitcoin situation will be if its price decreased to a low levels for long years from now and  may its mining rewards will  become uneconomic .so there are many solutions to avoid that .